# tooltip does not work after change of display style with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

I have a html element with a tooltip

```
<div class="parent">
    <div name="test_buttons" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="test" style="display:none;">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

this html object is not shown on page load (display = 'none'). I want to change that on mouse hover with javascript

```
$(".parent").mouseover(function(){
    var buttons = this.querySelectorAll('[name=test_buttons]');
    buttons[0].style.display = "inline";
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({trigger : 'hover'}); 
});

$(".parent").mouseout(function(){
    var buttons = this.querySelectorAll('[name=test_buttons]');
    buttons[0].style.display = "none";
});
```

but this does not seem to work. It works fine if I remove the display="none" statement. Any idea how to make the tooltip work in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ccg2kbbx/

```
<div class="parent" style="width:150px;height:150px;background-color:red;">
```

You need to make sure that your giving width and height to the parent element so that there is anything to mouseover.

Also make sure you have all the dependencies included (css and js) of jQuery and jQuery UI.

Comment: hi thanks for the comment... I had to specify the question a bit... in fact it all works if I remove the mouseout statement see above